# I cannot add gravity to my player in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I tried adding gravity to my player in pygame, but I can move the player with key controls but gravity is not working, Here I used sprite class for making this. I got the rect of the image then add the x momentum and y momentum. X momentum worked while moving the player but y momentum didn't work while adding the gravity. Please help!

```
# Platformer
import pygame

# Basic Setup
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Game Colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
light_blue = (105, 142, 255)

# Game Settings
game_title = "Platformer!"
screen_width = 1280
screen_height = 750
fps = 120

player_speed = 4
player_gravity = 0.2

# Main Window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption(game_title)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("IMGs/player.png")
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(screen_width / 2, screen_height / 2))

        self.x_momentum = 0
        self.y_momentum = 0
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def move(self):
        # Set the movement to zero at first
        self.x_momentum = 0
        self.y_momentum = 0

        # Move the player on key press
        if self.moving_right:
            self.x_momentum += player_speed
        elif self.moving_left:
            self.x_momentum -= player_speed

        # Add Gravity
        self.y_momentum += player_gravity

        # Move the player
        self.rect.x += self.x_momentum
        self.rect.y += self.y_momentum

    def update(self):
        self.move()


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        # Sprites
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

        # Player Sprite
        self.player = Player()
        self.all_sprites.add(self.player)

    def draw(self, surface):
        self.all_sprites.draw(surface)

    def update(self):
        self.all_sprites.update()


main_game = Main()


def main_game_loop():
    while True:
        # Handling Inputs
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit(0)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    main_game.player.moving_right = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    main_game.player.moving_left = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    main_game.player.moving_right = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    main_game.player.moving_left = False

        # Draw / Render
        screen.fill(light_blue)
        main_game.draw(screen)
        main_game.update()
        pygame.display.update()

        # Manage Speed
        clock.tick(fps)


main_game_loop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gravity doesn't work because `self.y_momentum` is set 0 at the begin of `Player.move`:

> ```py
> class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
>    # [...]
>
>    def move(self):
>        # Set the movement to zero at first
>        self.x_momentum = 0
>        self.y_momentum = 0
>  
>        # [...]
> ```

Since [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is supposed to represent an area on the screen, a `pygame.Rect` object can only store integral data.

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

The fraction part of the coordinates gets lost when the position stored in the *Rect* object is decremented:

> ```py
> # Move the player
> self.rect.x += self.x_momentum
> self.rect.y += self.y_momentum
> ```

If you want to store object positions with floating point accuracy, you have to store the location of the object in separate variables respectively attributes and to synchronize the `pygame.Rect` object. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates and assign it to the location (e.g. `.topleft`) of the rectangle:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        # [...]

        self.x = screen_width // 2
        self.y = screen_height // 2
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))

        # [...]

    def move(self):
        # [...]

        # Move the player
        self.x += self.x_momentum
        self.y += self.y_momentum
        self.rect.topleft = round(self.x), round(self.y)
```